# Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but () -> Unit was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting the above error with the below code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ScaffoldView(isScaffold: ()-> Boolean, selectedScreen: () -> NavItem){
    Scaffold(
        topBar =
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                title = {
                    when(selectedScreen().route){
                        Screens.ToDo.name -> PageOne()
                    }
                }
            )
    ) {paddingValues ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the variable i've passed from another function:

```
var selectedScreen by remember { mutableStateOf(listOfNavItems.first()) }
```

What is this error? and how to resolve this?

Also, just in case you wonder, I'm using lambda instead of doing it direct because i saw that google recommends using lambdas to improve performance.

Comment: Can you share the code for PageOne()?

Comment: @tomerpacific it's an empty composable function. Nothing in it. No parameter. No body.

Comment: what does it return (if at all)?

Comment: @tomerpacific PageOne returns nothing. its like this - 

(at)Composable
fun PageOne(){ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composables are functions, not instances. Wrap your TopAppBar call in a lambda, just like you did for the title and content:

```
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                title = {
                    when(selectedScreen().route){
                        Screens.ToDo.name -> PageOne()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    ) { ... }
```